# ReactJS issue with map and find

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, find

so i have an array of this type,

```
   (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {naam: "Tafel 1 ", id: 1, aantalPersonen: 3, aantalMinuten: 3, bezet: 1, …}
1: {naam: "Tafel 2 ", id: 2, aantalPersonen: 1, aantalMinuten: 3, bezet: 1, …}
2: {naam: "Tafel 3 ", id: 3, aantalPersonen: 2, aantalMinuten: 6, bezet: 1, …}
3: {naam: "Tafel 4", id: 4, aantalPersonen: 0, bezet: 0, tafelLayout: {…}}
4: {naam: "Tafel 5", id: 5, bezet: 0, aantalPersonen: 0, tafelLayout: {…}}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

i can map it to a component which then renders them all in divs and that works perfectly. Now what i want to do is render just a specific one.

```
this.state.tafels.find(tafel =>(tafel.id = 1))
```

finds for example the one i want to use

it has to be mapped to a component using props

```
  <PlattegrondResto

                        tafelNr={tafel.id}
                        tafelNaam = {tafel.naam}
                        tafelLayout={tafel.tafelLayout}
                        tafelaantalPersonen={tafel.aantalPersonen}
                        tafelMinuten = {tafel.aantalMinuten}
                        tafelBezet = {tafel.bezet}
                        tafelSelect={(tafelNr) => this.tafelSelect(tafelNr)}
                        tafelTijdInterval = {this.state.tijdInterval}

                    />
```

is there any way i can do that effectively ?
i tried everything i can think of so far

to map them all i use

```
 {this.state.tafels.map((tafel) =>
                    <PlattegrondResto

                        tafelNr={tafel.id}
                        tafelNaam = {tafel.naam}
                        tafelLayout={tafel.tafelLayout}
                        tafelaantalPersonen={tafel.aantalPersonen}
                        tafelMinuten = {tafel.aantalMinuten}
                        tafelBezet = {tafel.bezet}
                        tafelSelect={(tafelNr) => this.tafelSelect(tafelNr)}
                        tafelTijdInterval = {this.state.tijdInterval}

                    />


                )}
```

so i want to know is there a way to first use find and then map it to the component that is shown below

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can filter first and then map, consider the following code:

```
this.state.tafels.filter(tafel => tafel.id === 1).map(tafel => 
                  <PlattegrondResto
                    tafelNr={tafel.id}
                    tafelNaam = {tafel.naam}
                    tafelLayout={tafel.tafelLayout}
                    tafelaantalPersonen={tafel.aantalPersonen}
                    tafelMinuten = {tafel.aantalMinuten}
                    tafelBezet = {tafel.bezet}
                    tafelSelect={(tafelNr) => this.tafelSelect(tafelNr)}
                    tafelTijdInterval = {this.state.tijdInterval}
                />)
```

Comment: Ur a life saver , this is just perfect , this makes me able to use different floors now and then filter them by a selectable number in the state. Saves me so much time.

Comment: glad to be of help :)